# Applying DEM elevation adjustment parameters in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, dem, elevation, orthophoto

I have a nice DEM, created from UAV data, which I want to process further in QGIS, my platform of first choice. In order to represent the evelation of each pixel correctly, I have to adjust the 'elevation adjustment parameters' like Z-scale and Z-offset. In Globalmapper, I was able to do it. Also in the manual of ArcGIS, it is discussed (http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//009t0000003t000000).

I do, however, not encounter the way how to do it in QGIS.

Does have anyone a clue or advice on how to do that in QGIS?

Comment: Out of curiosity, which software did you use to generate the DEM from the UAV photos?

Answer (score 3):

That depends on what you want to do. For example, the Relief tool lets you define the Z factor:

[image]

http://underdark.wordpress.com/2012/01/19/a-guide-to-beautiful-reliefs-in-qgis/

---

Update:

If you need to apply the corrections only once, you can use raster calculator.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. The DEM is generated based on a series of UAV photo's using a cloud solution. With the DEM, they give following parameters in order to represent correctly the height of each pixel: Z Altitude Offset (m): 55.6382493318075291 DEM Z Scale (m): 0.15172011985822564

Comment: I'm not sure I totally understand what that means, but could you just use the raster calculator to apply those corrections once?

Comment: Many thanks, I was able to do it with the rastar calculator. Same results as in globalmapper were obtained.

Comment: @ArnoudCuppens, for good form in stackexchange, it would be great if you would take the time to add an answer and mark it as accepted, with the details of how you used raster calculator to solve to problem...